# Override Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Grid

Tags: magento-1.9

Config.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Mera_Cadh>
        <version>0.1.1</version>
    </Mera_Cadh>
</modules>
<stores>
    <admin>
        <!-- override default admin design package and theme -->
        <design>
            <package>
                <name>default</name>
            </package>
            <theme>
                <default>meraopus</default>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>

<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>

                  <permissions_user>Mera_Cadh_Block_Adminhtml_Permissions_User</permissions_user>
                  <permissions_user_grid>Mera_Cadh_Block_Adminhtml_Permissions_User_Grid</permissions_user_grid>
                  <permissions_user_edit>Mera_Cadh_Block_Adminhtml_Permissions_User_Edit</permissions_user_edit>
                  <permissions_user_edit_tab_main>Mera_Cadh_Block_Adminhtml_Permissions_User_Edit_Tab_Main</permissions_user_edit_tab_main>
                  <permissions_user_edit_tab_roles>Mera_Cadh_Block_Adminhtml_Permissions_User_Edit_Tab_Roles</permissions_user_edit_tab_roles>

            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
        <Mera_Cadh>
        <class>Mera_Cadh_Block</class>
        </Mera_Cadh>
    </blocks>

</global>
    <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <mera_cadh before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mera_Cadh</mera_cadh>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

My file located app\code\local\Mera\Cadh\Block\Adminhtml\Permissions\User\Grid.php
Code:

```
class Mera_Cadh_Block_Adminhtml_Permissions_User_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Grid
```

I am not able to override file. Please help me

Comment: Add your module xml file in this

Answer (score 1):

i have used same your code and it worked for me just namespace and module name were different. Please check if not any spelling mistakes in folder name.

**Edit :**

1) Clear cache and put exit in __construct function.

2) check the file permission in case.

3) any other module re-write the same block file.
     I have checked by rewrite the same block file with other module too. It do not call the 2nd module rewrite file.

Comment: I check  spelling but i dint find where it is wrong ..Please help me

Comment: i am not sure about the spelling mistake. that was just suggesion as your code worked when i tried on my magento 1.9.1.0 setup. is other re-writes work for you?

Comment: First option not work for me it show blank page 2nd  I am using windows .I have change folder permission  Third option no i have create sperate module

Comment: sorry if i misunderstood the comment, but if you place exit in the __construct function of your rewrite file and it shows you blank page, it means your rewrite works.